# Capturing packets on loopback

Tags: c++, macos, endianness, libpcap

This code works perfectly fine on Ubuntu 16.04 and prints correct value (ETHERTYPE_IP) when I toss around UDP bytes via loopback interface:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <net/ethernet.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    auto pcap = pcap_open_live("lo0", BUFSIZ, 0, 1000, errbuf);

    pcap_loop(pcap,0, [] (u_char *self, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
                          const u_char *packet) {
        auto eth = (struct ether_header *) packet;
        auto eth_type = ntohs(eth->ether_type);
        std::cout << "eth_type: " << std::hex << eth_type << std::endl;
    }, nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

netcat:

```
➜  ~ nc -uv -l 54321
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 54321)

➜  ~ nc -4u localhost 54321
hello
```

Program output:

```
➜  ~ sudo ./a.out
eth_type: 800
```

However on OS X 10.11.5 it prints **eth_type: 4011**. Interesting that it works fine with **en1** adapter.

Why there is such a difference between loopback and non-loopback adapters and what is the correct way to capture packets on both?

**Update:**
tcpdump also works:

```
➜  ~ sudo tcpdump -i lo0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo0, link-type NULL (BSD loopback), capture size 262144 bytes
15:09:00.160664 IP localhost.54321 > localhost.63543: UDP, length 4
```

Comment: You might have to use "lo0" and not "lo". To compile this on a mac try:
    clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lpcap  test.cpp -o test
...I also get garbage values for ether_type.

Comment: that's a typo in snippet, it is indeed lo0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link type is not ethernet, the header does not contain suitable data for ether_header.

Add this code after fetching the handle with pcap_open_live to see the link-layer header type:

```
if (pcap_datalink(pcap) != DLT_EN10MB) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Device doesn't provide Ethernet headers - link type was %d\n", pcap_datalink(pcap));
    return 1;
}
```

Running this indicates that the linktype value for lo0 is 0, DLT_NULL. The documentation states that this means "BSD loopback encapsulation; the link layer header is a 4-byte field, in host byte order, containing a PF_ value from socket.h for the network-layer protocol of the packet."

Indeed, when I look at the the first 4 bytes of the ether_dhost field I see the value 2, corresponding to PF_INET. In the end, this doesn't help you much if you are trying to distinguish UDP packets.

You can find more documentation here: http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html